# Among these figures circle, square, rectangle, isosceles triangle which has the greatest perimeter had the same area?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Among these figures circle, square, rectangle, isosceles triangle which has the greatest perimeter had the same area geometrically ?

Answer (score 4):

As it stands, this question doesn't have a definitive answer. Given any area, you can make a rectangle or isosceles triangle having that area, with arbitrarily large perimeter.

Now, if the question were asking which can have the greatest area given a perimeter, then it would be more interesting (and the answer would be a circle).